# Como controlar os filtros de uma query que persiste no mongodb

Tags: query, mongodb, spring-boot

tenho essa query na minha api:

```
@Query("{$and: ["
            + "{'online': ?5}, "
            + "{'locations.appointmentTimeRanges.weekday': ?6}, "
            + "{'specialties.name': ?7}, "
            + "{'healthInsurances.name' : ?8}"
        + "]}")
```

Eu preciso que ao passar os parâmetros, quando não vier algum campo preenchido deve desconsiderar certo filtro.

Exemplo: Veio como parâmetro apenas o online e o weekday, do jeito que está ele procura também por specialties.name e healthInsurances.name como sendo vazio e não acha nada.

Eu quero que em ambos momentos ele procure por todos os atributos juntos ou por alguns enviados pelo cliente, ignorando filtro em que o parâmetro não veio preenchido. Como no meu exemplo não veio specialties.name e healthInsurances.name eu quero ignorá-los na busca.

Espero que tenham entendido minha pergunta.

Comment: Acho que o caminho é [por aqui](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)

Comment: Está usando algum backend?

Comment: Wallace estou usando Java (Spring JPA)

Comment: tenta assim: "{'online': ?5 || { $exists: true } }, "

Comment: Resolvi com $where galera.      {$or : [{'specialties.name': { '$regex': ?2, $options: 'i'}}, { $where: '?4' }]} usa-se o $or e ele só realiza o filtro dessa linha da query se '?4' for true, que é um campo booleano que eu passo por parâmetro.

Comment: Se resolveu o problema, poste a solução como resposta. Não precisa alterar o título.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi dessa forma:

```
 @Query("{$and: ["
        +"{'online': ?0}, " 
        +"{'locations.appointmentTimeRanges.weekday': { '$regex': ?1 }}, "
        +"{$or : [{'specialties.name': { '$regex': ?2, $options: 'i'}}, $where: '?4' }]}, " 
        +"{$or : [{'healthInsurances.name' : { '$regex': ?3, $options: 'i'}}, { $where: '?5' }]} "     
    + "]}")
```

O segredo é usar o $or: e o $where, no $where eu passo um valor booleano, caso seja true ele vai considerar o filtro daquele campo, caso seja falso vai desconsiderar. Portanto os valores ?4 e ?5 são booleanos que passei por parâmetro apenas verificando se specialties.name e healthInsurances.name são diferentes de null, se sim considera eles no filtro, se não retira do filtro.